# I want to know this picture is a tooltip or an alert dialog

Tags: flutter, dialog, tooltip

To implement service guidelines, a higer to appear only the first time the user launches the app. I'm trying to implement a feature that allows the user to close the speech bubble. I'm trying to refer to another app, but is the widget with that phrase written an alert dialog or a tooltip? If
it's a tooltip, I'm wondering how to get it to appear right on the screen without the user pressing a button.
Thank you for your reply

[tooltip? or dialog?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Tqi8.jpg)

I tried to use supertooltip to display the guideline whe the app is run fir the first time without pressing a button, but it failed
this is my code

```
 final _controller = SuperTooltipController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _showFirstTimeUserTooltip();
  }

  void _showFirstTimeUserTooltip() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    _controller.showTooltip();
    });
  }
...
 
   GestureDetector(
                onTap: _showFirstTimeUserTooltip,
                child: SuperTooltip(
                  showBarrier: true,
                  controller: _controller,
                  content: const Text(
                    "text",
                    softWrap: true,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: it's a Tooltip , dialog and Alert dialog makes the screen go dark around the dialog